# Wordpress docker-compose.yaml get error: Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker-compose

I am trying to start wordpress using the following docker-compose.yaml file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name IP www.mysite.com;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER:$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD:$MYSQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network
  wordpress:
      depends_on:
        - db
      image: wordpress:6.0.1-fpm-alpine
      container_name: wordpress
      restart: unless-stopped
      env_file: .env
      environment:
        - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
        - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
        - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
      volumes:
        - wordpress:/var/www/html
      networks:
        - app-network
  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network
volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**.env file:**

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

But I get an error:
**Error establishing a database connection**
I get the feeling that wordpress doesn't see MySQL on port 3306, although the docker ps -a shows that everything is working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urnpr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaxy1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER:$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD:$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD:1
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network
  wordpress:
      depends_on:
        - db
      #image: wordpress:6.0.1-fpm-alpine
      image: wordpress:php8.1-apache
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
      container_name: wordpress
      restart: unless-stopped
      env_file: .env
      environment:
        - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
        - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
        - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
        - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
      volumes:
        - wordpress:/var/www/html
      networks:
        - app-network
  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network
volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and create locally `nginx-conf/nginx.conf`

```
 server {
    listen 80 default;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all; 
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @nginx;
    }

    location ~ ^/.user.ini {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  .(css|js)$ {
        allow all; 
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location ~*  .(svg|svgz)$ {
        types {}
        default_type image/svg+xml;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location @nginx {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80;
    }

    location ~[^?]*/$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80;
    }

    location ~/. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggested the setting you suggested, now the site is not accessible from the internet, even if instead of localhost in the nginx settings, the real IP address and domain are specified.
I don't use WP outside of a test environment, I need it to be accessible from the internet as well as via cloudflare in my mood to redirect from domain name to IP.
The fact is that I need exactly the version of wordpress, or not higher than 6.0.x
And I didn’t quite understand why Apache was specified in the nginx bundle.

Comment: I added nginx config what i used  in topic

Comment: Well, you did not provide all of your requirements... `@apache` in nginx config is just a label, you can replace it with `@anything`. You can also update `server_name localhost;` to `server_name _;` which will catch-all any hostname, which you can configure outside Docker

Comment: I actually did so, but nothing works, with my configuration everything ran, but for some reason WordPress could not connect to MySQL. I went into the wordpress container to look at wp-config.php and make sure the database password was set. The problem is something trivial and I can't figure out what it is. Perhaps a directive needs to be added:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "33060:33060"
But that didn't help either.